# OCI and Azure - How to secure OCI hosted API by Azure APIM

Tags: oracle, azure, api, cloud

I have API working on OCI. I want to consume this API into my IIS-hosted site. But before consuming this API, need to provide security to it by Azure API management.
As I am recently started working on cloud infrastructure, please guide me.

Comment: what is OCI? Oracle Call interface? Is it a web service? Is it PaaS / SaaS / IaaS ?

Comment: OCI - oracle cloud infrastructure.